# PowerShell Multiple -and operators?

Tags: powershell

Is there a simpler way to do this? Or does it require me to type out each -and/-notlike for each of the criteria?

```
Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "<Enter Domain OU>"} |
Select-Object UserPrincipalName | 
Where-Object `
{$_.UserPrincipalName -notlike 'a-*' `
-and $_.UserPrincipalName -notlike 'falkon*' `
-and $_.UserPrincipalName -notlike 'test*' `
-and $_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '*whiteboard*' `
-and $_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '*CSC*' `
-and $_.UserPrincipalName -notlike '*autopilot*'} |
Sort-Object UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: you can always use `-match`: `$_.UserPrincipalName -match "a-|falkon|test|whiteboard|CSC"`. Since it looks like you're querying AD, you can use the filter to search for those keywords at runtime as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, he can't use -match in an AD filter, but he can use -notlike. The poster can drop the backticks and use operators to continue lines at least. Distinguishedname can't be in an AD filter.

```
get-aduser -filter "UserPrincipalName -notlike 'a-*' -and
  UserPrincipalName -notlike 'falkon*' -and
  UserPrincipalName -notlike 'test*' -and
  UserPrincipalName -notlike '*whiteboard*' -and
  UserPrincipalName -notlike '*CSC*' -and
  UserPrincipalName -notlike 
  '*autopilot*'" -searchbase 'DC=stackoverflow,DC=com' -resultsetsize 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following string manipulation to build an LDAP Filter for less verbosity on your script and to leverage [Active Directory Filtering capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)).

Worth mentioning, as more users are under the `SearchBase` Organizational Unit the faster `-Filter` / `-LDAPFilter` becomes compared to `Where-Object`.

```
$ou = 'OU=some,OU=ou,DC=some,DC=domain'
$notLike = 'a-*', 'falkon*', 'test*', '*whiteboard*', '*CSC*', '*autopilot*'
$filter = '(&(!userprincipalname={0}))' -f ($notLike -join ')(!userprincipalname=')

$params = @{
    SearchBase  = $ou
    SearchScope = 'OneLevel' # Or SubTree for all child OUs under `$ou`
    LDAPFilter  = $filter
}
Get-ADUser @params | Sort-Object UserPrincipalName
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't return anything. I am not too familiar with the -filter parameter either.

Comment: @kooleosis if it didn't return anything is likely because there are no users under the "SearchBase" OU which's `userprincipalname` is "not like" the wildcards in `$notLike`